# Spring boot docker plugin requires removing the image everytime

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, docker, spring-boot

I created a basic spring boot app and I am using the `docker-maven-plugin`
to build the docker image.

Every time I make a change to the app, I have to remove the container and start it again.
`docker rm -f <container-name>`
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -d <IMAGE> --name some-app`

Is there any way I can just  restart the container and the new changes take effect.

Here is docker plugin in my pom file.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD demo-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar basic-boot-app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /basic-boot-app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/basic-boot-app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try in given way**
>
> Structure of java aplication

```
Demo
└── src
|    ├── main
|    │   ├── java
|    │   │   └── org
|    │   │       └── demo
|    │   │           └── App.java
|    │   └── resources
|    │       └── application.properties
|    └── test
|         └── java
|               └── org
|                   └── demo
|                         └── App.java  
├──── Dockerfile
├──── pom.xml
```

> Content of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.executablejar</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <docker.image.prefix>springDemo</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

> Content of Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/demo.jar demo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo.jar"]
```

> Commands to build and run image
>
> - Go to the directory of project.Lets say D:/Demo

```
$ cd D/demo
$ mvn clean install
$ docker build demo .
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -t demo
```

Here you can find video : [Spring Boot with Docker](https://youtu.be/Ojs9I-gnkc8)